# web server not reachable

Tags: web-server, centos7, apache2

On a centos-7, I have installed web server but I can not see the test page through web browser.

```
# yum list httpd*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.iphh.net
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: mirror.wiuwiu.de
 * updates: mirror.daniel-jost.net
Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64                                                2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4                                        @updates
httpd-manual.noarch                                       2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4                                        @updates
httpd-tools.x86_64                                        2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4                                        @updates
Available Packages
httpd-devel.x86_64                                        2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4                                        updates 
httpd-itk.x86_64                                          2.4.7.04-1.el7                                               epel    
# ls /etc/init.d/
functions  iprdump  iprinit  iprupdate  netconsole  network  README
# ps aux | grep httpd
root     28879  0.0  0.8 240340  8340 ?        Ss   01:03   0:00  /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28880  0.0  0.3 242352  3432 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28881  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28882  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28883  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28884  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28885  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root     29076  0.0  0.0 112640   972 pts/0    S+   01:09   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
# ps aux | grep apache
apache   28880  0.0  0.3 242352  3432 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28881  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28882  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28883  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28884  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28885  0.0  0.3 242424  3700 ?        S    01:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root     29078  0.0  0.0 112640   980 pts/0    S+   01:09   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Looking at the logs, I see

```
 # cat /var/log/httpd/access_log 
 # cat /var/log/httpd/error_log 
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.055960 2017] [core:notice] [pid 28879] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.057776 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 28879] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
 AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.073921 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 28879] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.074540 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 28879] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.101221 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28879] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Tue May 16 01:03:35.101259 2017] [core:notice] [pid 28879] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Any idea to debug more?

Comment: Hi can you check your firewall? you sure http is open?

Comment: How are you trying to view the web page exactly? What is the location, where is the server? What is the exact error message from browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check firewall(firewalld) can permit port # you want to use in **active zone**

`sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=your_zone --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

A good example is follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/centos-7-open-firewall-port

And for more firewalld configuration:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld?rd=FirewallD#Predefined_services

2. Confirm selinux allows port # you want to use(normally 80/tcp)

check:
`senamage port -l`

modify:
`senamage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 80`

You may change more ports.

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-ad837f60830442ae77a81aedd10c20305a811388

Comment: The first solution worked. Also, I don't have `senamage`.

Comment: `semanage` command is included policycoreutils-python package. But if you did not plan to change port #, you will not need to install and check with it.